# Fullcalendar timelineMonth day/date formatting considering locale

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to find how to apply locale info to timelineMonth cols formatting.

Seems that dayNames, dayNamesShort, monthNames and monthNamesShort are not applied only to that specific view (see image)

[timelineMonth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy5My.png)

Is there a specific option to format that particolar rows?

The rest of the views (calendar-scheduler) month and names are correctly displayed using provided the arrays of day and month names

```
 CalendarOptions options = new CalendarOptions();
options.dayNames = new JsArray<>();
    options.dayNamesShort = new JsArray<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      options.dayNames.setAt(i, DateTimeFormat.getWeekDay((i - 1) % 7));
      options.dayNamesShort.setAt(i, DateTimeFormat.getCompressedWeekDay((i - 1) % 7));
    }
    options.monthNames = new JsArray<>();
    options.monthNamesShort = new JsArray<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      options.monthNames.setAt(i, DateTimeFormat.getMonth(i + 1));
      options.monthNamesShort.setAt(i, DateTimeFormat.getCompressedMonth(i + 1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've solved the issue by myself.

in timeline we have to manage such info by the slotLabelFormat opt, (Array)

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat